# latex3: errors I don't understand

Tags: latex3

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__test_current_choice_against_version: { I'm working }

\seq_new:N \g__user_defined_choice_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\choices}{ O{;} m }{
    \texttt{#2}\par
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \g__user_defined_choice_seq  #1  #2
    \seq_show:N \g__user_defined_choice_seq
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

Choosing \choices{x;y;z;w}

\end{document}
```

and it doesn't seem to be doing at all what I expect.

**First** the `\seq_show:N` is creating an error and the document does not produce output.   The error is:

```
The sequence \g__user_defined_choice_seq contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {x}.
<recently read> }

l.17 Choosing \choices{x;y;z;w}

?
```

**Secondly** and the reason I was trying `\seq_show:N......` was because my argument is not getting split.  I'm expecting that `\g__user_defined_choice_seq` should have four elements and not just one.

**Edit**

I've also tried using `\seq_gset_split` thinking that that might be the problem with how the argument is getting split, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing braces around `#1` and `#2`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__user_defined_choice_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\choices}{ O{;} m }
 {
  \texttt{#2}\par
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__user_defined_choice_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_show:N \l__user_defined_choice_seq
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

Choosing \choices{x;y;z;w}

\end{document}
```

`n` type arguments should always be in braces, while `N` arguments shouldn't (and should consist of only one token).

Also you're mixing "local" and "global". Variables with the `g_` prefix should always be acted upon globally. So either use

```
\seq_gset_split:Nnn
```

or use a local variables.

Comment: On to the next question then.